# Filter array with jq based on nested values

Tags: json, aws-cli, jq

I am writing some bash scripts to help automate the management of AWS resources. I am using `aws-cli` and `jq`, and so far things have been great.

I am tagging my resources with custom tags. In certain circumstances I would like to filter a list of resources based on both `Key` and `Value` of the custom tag. But I am having trouble working out a succinct `jq` query to do it.

So, for example, if the (trimmed) JSON output for my ec2 instances is like:

```
[
    {
        "PublicIpAddress": "11.22.33.44",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "55.66.77.88",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "live199.blah.com",
                "Key": "Name"
            },
            {
                "Value": "live-standalone",
                "Key": "hc-class"
            }
        ]
    }
]
[
    {
        "PublicIpAddress": "111.222.333.444",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "555.666.777.888",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "staging99.blah.com",
                "Key": "Name"
            },
            {
                "Value": "staging-standalone",
                "Key": "hc-class"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

...and I need find the entry where `Tags.Key == "hc-class"` and `Tags.Value = "staging-standalone"`, how do I do it in a succinct way with `jq`?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can just do it straight from aws CLI using JMESPATH, look at the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354116/using-jmespath-and-aws-ec2-describe-instances-to-output-multiple-tag-values which details some example how to work iwth that

Comment: What do you mean by "entry"?  Since "Tags" is an array, the inclusion criterion is unclear. It might help if you gave the expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering JSON object list with jq by matching multiple objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973816/filtering-json-object-list-with-jq-by-matching-multiple-objects)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the given input, the following filter produces the output as shown below:

```
.[] | select(any(.Tags[]; .Key == "hc-class" and .Value == "staging-standalone"))
```

Output:

```
{
  "PublicIpAddress": "111.222.333.444",
  "PrivateIpAddress": "555.666.777.888",
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Value": "staging99.blah.com",
      "Key": "Name"
    },
    {
      "Value": "staging-standalone",
      "Key": "hc-class"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm quite new to JQ, but I feel like I have a solution here:

https://jqplay.org/s/DljtxNX_72

```
select((.[0].Tags[1].Key) == "hc-class" and (.[0].Tags[1].Value) == "staging-standalone")
```